# Java chat client and server

Tags: java

I have written a chat server that works with telnet. I wrote a client to connect to the server. In the terminal, I run the client by giving it the name of the file and the ip address and port. It appears to connect because it closes the server and the following error occurs:

```
  Connection reset
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:130)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:316)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:379)
        at ChatServer$HandleClient.<init>(ChatServer.java:47)
        at ChatServer.process(ChatServer.java:18)
        at ChatServer.main(ChatServer.java:23)
```

My chat server code is:

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class  ChatServer {
      ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList<HandleClient> clients = new ArrayList<HandleClient>();
      Socket client;

      public void process() throws Exception  {
          ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9020,10);
          out.println("Server Started...");
          while( true) {
             client = server.accept();
             HandleClient c = new HandleClient(client);
             clients.add(c);
         }  // end of while
      }
      public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
          new ChatServer().process();
      } // end of main

      public void bc(String user, String message)  {
            // send message to all connected users
            for ( HandleClient c : clients )
               if ( ! c.getUserName().equals(user) )
                  c.sendMessage(user,message);
      }

      class  HandleClient extends Thread {
            String name = "";
        BufferedReader input;
        PrintWriter output;

        public HandleClient(Socket  client) throws Exception {
             // get input and output streams
         start();
         input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( client.getInputStream())) ;
         output = new PrintWriter ( client.getOutputStream(),true);
         output.println("Welcome to Kimberly's Chat room");
         // receives the name of the client
         output.println("Enter your name: ");
         // read name of the client
         name  = input.readLine();
         users.add(name); // adds the name of the client to the vector
         output.println("Thanks for joining " + name + ". If you need help, type \"help\" for a list of commands.");
         //start();
            }

            public void sendMessage(String uname,String  msg)  {
            output.println(uname + ":" + msg);
        }

            public String getUserName() {
                return name;
            }

        public String toString() {
                return name;
            }

            public void run()  {
                 String line;
             try    {
                   while(true)   {
                line = input.readLine();
                String[] temp;
                temp = line.split(":");
                    //checks different input from the client
                //checks to see if the client wants to terminate their connection
                //removes the client's name from the list
                if ("adios".equals(line)){
                    output.println("Server closing connection...");
                    clients.remove(this);
                    users.remove(name);
                    break;
                        }
                //checks to see if the client typed in help to receive a list of the commands
                else if("help".equals(line)){
                    output.println("Here is a list of user commands:");
                    output.println("adios: exit");
                    output.println("help: lists the commands and their syntax");
                    output.println("get: receives a response of the entire chat buffer");
                    output.println("name: receives a response of \"OK\" and adds the name to a list");
                }
                else if("getNames".equals(line)){
                    output.println(users.toString());
                }
                else if("name".equals(temp[0])){
                    users.add(temp[1]);
                    output.println("OK");
                }
                else if("push".equals(temp[0])){
                    buffer.add(name + ":" + temp[1]);
                    output.println("OK");
                }
                else if("get".equals(line)){
                    output.println(buffer.toString());
                }
                else if("test".equals(temp[0])){
                    output.println(temp[1].toString());
                }
                else{
                    bc(name,line); // method  of outer class - send messages to all
                }
               } // end of while
             } // try
             catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             }
             try{
            client.close();
             }
             catch(Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             }
            } // end of run()
       } // end of inner class
}
```

My client code is:

```
public class  ChatClient {
    PrintWriter output;
    BufferedReader input;
    Socket client;

    public ChatClient(String ip, int port) throws Exception {
    client = new Socket(ip,port);
    input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( client.getInputStream()) ) ;
        output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
        String ip= args[0];
        int port= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            new ChatClient(ip,port);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            out.println( "Error --> " + ex.getMessage());
        }

    } // end of main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
input.readLine();
```

to your ChatClient class after you send data to server

Comment: Ok. It doesn't crash anymore, but I get this: "Server Started...
null" The server is not sending a prompt to the client to enter their name.